# How to have doxygen output a graph for Modules?

Tags: c, graph, module, doxygen

For my project in C I was able to make html documentation by doxygen (version 1.9.3).
Modules are listed in their tab, but clicking on one of them I see only its data structures and, if set up, call and caller graphs for its functions, but not a diagram with group dependencies.
Such a diagram is supported, as stated in the official documentation: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_group_graphs

My code
File_1.c:

```
// Header of this file

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
///\defgroup File_1
///@{
///
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#include "File_2.h"

// Module body

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
///@}
///
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

File_2.c:

```
// Header of this file

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
///\defgroup File_2
///@{
///
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

// Module body

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
///@}
///
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

File_2.h:

```
// Header of this file

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
///\addtogroup  File_2
///@{
///
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

// Macros

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
///@}
///
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Doxygen settings related to graphs are at default (except HAVE_DOT), and I get no errors nor warnings in the log.

Any idea about the possible cause? Or could you please point me at a simple example?

Comment: Without knowing how you defined your groups it is not possible to give any sensible advise. Please show as small example and also show the differences between your settings and the deafult doxygen settings (i.e. the result of `doxygen -x`).

Comment: Did you see in the manual: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html and tried this example?

Comment: @albert Thanks for your comments, I edited the post with code and settings. I hade seen the manual and the example, but I did not find any graph there as well.

Comment: That you didn't see the graphs with the exan\mple from https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html can be explained as in the examples the doxygen setting is `HAVE_DOT=NO`, with `HAVE_DOT=YES` I see the the images. I'll give your example a try ...

Comment: Looks like you have no `defgroup` hierarchy as shown in the doxygen example, hence no image.

Comment: @albert OK, so "direct groups dependencies" in https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_group_graphs means hierarchical, not include dependency (that is what I am looking for). I was thinking about DIRECTORY_GRAPH, but this is a bit restrictive, since every module must be in a different folder. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Doxygen has an include graph that can be obaitned per file but there is nothing I know of in this respect for groups.

Comment: @albert Thank you anyway. If you write an answer, I will close this question.

Comment: I added a feature request to the doxygen repository in GitHub: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/9224